# How to access Custom View in dynamic feature module in XML?

Tags: android, dynamic-delivery

How can I access the custom view class of the on-demand dynamic module in XML of the main app?

Without dynamic module I can simply access as below in XML but I am not sure in case of on demand dynamic module if it is even possible to access custom view of dynamic module?

```
<com.mymodule.MyCustomView />
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?